# Intent not working as expected when used with Class name

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have this following code, in Class named Menu which extends from ListActivity.
When I click on listitem the Toast line is getting executed properly but nothing happens after that, I guess code in catch block is getting executed and that Intent part is throwing some exception. Do you see any problem with this definition ?

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    try {
        Toast.makeText(Menu.this, "Clicked!!", 5000).show();
        Class myClass = Class.forName("com.palye.first.MainActivity");
        Intent menuI = new Intent(Menu.this, myClass);
        startActivity(menuI);
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Post the exception stack trace.

Comment: Is `com.example.first.MainActivity` in the same application? Is it declared in the manifest?

Comment: @Nambari - that's probably another part, I am still trying to figure out, how to get the contents of stack trace, I even tried system.out.println instead and still doesn't show anything, any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: @Henry - yes that class is in same application and it's even defined as activity in mainfest... but I guess when you use the "com.example.first.MainActivity" in this scenario it doesn't refer manifest file, since we are passing it as a string to Class instance, that's what I think, but I could be wrong

Comment: Can you show us the logcat messages?

Comment: This is the content for CLASSPATH environment variable
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip;C:\Users\Amey Palyekar\workspace\First\bin\classes\com;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\lib`

Comment: Here it is - I finally got to print the error messages (Thanks @Henry) `12-28 21:26:53.050: E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG(707): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.palye.first.MainActivity   12-28 21:26:53.050: E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG(707): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.palye.first.MainActivity  12-28 21:26:53.050: E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG(707): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.palye.first.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.playe.first-1.apk]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do know if you own the Activity you can create an explicit intent:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Menu.this, MainActivity.class);
```

then you don't need the `try catch` either

Comment: Yes i've already tried that, but without any luck
`Intent menuI = new Intent(Menu.this, com.playe.first.MainActivity.class);`

Comment: @ameyx yes, then check your LogCat after that, it will be a different error saying to declare the Activity in your manifest or something else. Also why are your prefixing your class with the package name? Let the IDE auto import it so you don't screw it up

Comment: As per yor suggestion i tried this - `Class myClass = Class.forName("MainActivity");`
but it still shows the same classnotfoundException in logcat. 
 Later I even tried to import package com.playe.first.* and still no luck

Comment: @ameyx your not listening I didn't say that at all. Stick to the code I put in the answer, Update your imports, run your code and look at your **new** stack trace in LogCat

Comment: Yes thanks, this worked!  `Intent menuI = new Intent(Menu.this, MainActivity.class);`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the

```
    Class myClass = Class.forName("com.example.first.MainActivity");
```

isn't enough, because it will not load the class. I  need to make a `myClass.newInstance()`; and than use the `myClass`, even if I am not using the created object.

Try it , maybe it will solve your problem.

Comment: ` 
try {
 myClass.newInstance();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
 System.out.println(e.getMessage());
 System.out.println(e.getCause().getMessage());
    } 
`

I tried this but unfortunately it still doesn't give any favourable result

Comment: sometimes this is solve my problem, when I shouldn't have at all. Are you sure you have declared the com.example.first.MainActivity in manifest?! it will throw a classNotfoundEcxeption if isn't declared in xml. If is declared and is linked and exported to project it shouldn't be a problem to load it

Comment: This is the activity defined in manifest.xml - (skipping some unrelated code)
' <activity
android:name="com.playe.first.MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.STARTINGPOINT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>`

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere I saw a few package names are excluded from loading, deploying, forgot which ones. As I remember one is the "android" other is the "internal" or "example" . Because I am switching / mixing the iOS / Android / Java EE I am not sure where isn't allowed and which one.

Try to rename / refactor the "`example`" to "`my`" package, maybe it will solve. For Android Market for sure isn't allowed to deploy with "`example`"

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try `MainActivity.class` instead? e.g., `Intent menuI = new Intent(Menu.this, MainActivity.class);`

Can you post the logcat output?

Comment: when I try to pass MainActivity.this - eclipse flags an error - No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope
**I have pasted the logcat details above under comment for question, I can't paste complete log due to text limitation**